# how to only replace \n which has some char after that

Tags: python, regex, string, newline

I converted pdf to txt using pdfminer. Issue is pdfminer adds \n after line end in pdf but sentence is not ending there. you can see each line is taken as a sentence in below text which is not right. I also gave other version of text to show where are new lines chars. for example

```
quan-
tum population.
```

should be in one sentence. I so I replace \n with " and this issue is solved. But other \n are also replace which I don't want to.

```
Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)

Muhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg

Abstract
With advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integrated
with Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement. Although these
properties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in Quantum
Evolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quan-
tum population. In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum population
of QEA to avoid premature convergence

'Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)\n\nMuhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, 
Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg\n\nAbstract\nWith advancement in Quantum computing, classical 
algorithms are adapted and integrated\nwith Quantum properties such as qubit representation 
and entanglement', ' Although these\nproperties perform better however pre-mature 
convergence is the main issue in Quantum\nEvolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only 
the best individual to update quan-\ntum population', ' In this paper, we introduced a new 
way to update the quantum population\nof QEA to avoid premature convergence',
```

I have tried this code.

```
lines =tokenize.sent_tokenize(txt_str)
for l in lines:
    s = l.replace('\n', '')
    print(s)
```

This results in this.

```
Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)Muhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer BegAbstractWith advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integratedwith Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement.
Although theseproperties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in QuantumEvolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quan-tum population.
In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum populationof QEA to avoid premature convergence.
```

but this is not wanted text. I want text in this version.

```
Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)

Muhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg

Abstract
With advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integrated with Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement. Although these properties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in Quantum Evolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quan-tum population. In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum population of QEA to avoid premature convergence
```

I don't want empty lines to disappear. I hope you understand.

Comment: Use regex and capture the text groups and add a '\n' or more after them to get this output

Comment: i tried using r'\\n\w' but this replaces the last char too.

Comment: So on what basis do you want to preserve the newline after "Abstract"?

Comment: any \n between a sentence should be removes. "Abstract" is only one word sentence so \n should not be removed. qun-\ntum is past to previous sentence so this \n  should be removed. @alaniwi

Comment: @shahidhamdam So essentially your rule is to remove newlines unless either of the following apply: (a) the line contains one or zero words, or (b) the _next_ line contains no words -- do you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=\S)(?<!\bAbstract)\n(?=\S)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/crj3aD/1

Python script:

```
inp = "Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)\n\nMuhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg\n\nAbstract\nWith advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integrated\nwith Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement', ' Although these\nproperties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in Quantum\nEvolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quan-\ntum population', ' In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum population\nof QEA to avoid premature convergence"

output = re.sub(r'(?<=\S)(?<!\bAbstract)\n(?=\S)', ' ', inp)
print(output)
```

There are more conditions.

```
(?<=\S)(?<!\bAbstract)(?:\n|\\n)(?=\S)
```

Try this for your another condition.

https://regex101.com/r/crj3aD/2

Comment: Why everyone is giving answer for specific scenario?

Comment: quan-\ntum this \n is still there so this word will be broken into two sentences. DON'T want this to happen

Comment: this is working 80%. There are yet some situations where it removes extra empty new lines which shouldn't be removed but I am up voting this answer. Thank you

Comment: @shahidhamdam can you list down the cases where it's not working

Comment: "2. Background
    2.1. Evolutionary Algorithms"

these two are headings and on different lines, your solutions output them on same line like this
2. Background 2.1. Evolutionary Algorithms

in comment it can't be formatted, can it?

Comment: can we go in chat? I don't know how to make this a chat

Comment: join me in chat
 https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/216122/remove-n-with-vks?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

lines = tokenize.sent_tokenize(txt_str)

s = lines.replace('\n', ' ')

print(s)

Answer (score 0):

This should do this for you:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^(.*\(BQCEA\))(.*Beg)(Abstract)(With.*)", re.DOTALL)

try:
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
        line = f.read()
        # remove some unwanted characters
        r = line.replace('\\n', "").replace("'", "").replace("\n", "")
        print(r)
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, r):
            print(match.group(1))
            print('\n')
            print(match.group(2))
            print('\n')
            print(match.group(3))
            print(match.group(4))
except Exception as er:
    print(er)
```

Output:

```
Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)


Muhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba,Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg


Abstract
With advancement in Quantum computing, classicalalgorithms are adapted and integratedwith Quantum properties such as qubit representationand entanglement,  Although theseproperties perform better however pre-matureconvergence is the main issue in QuantumEvolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses onlythe best individual to update quan-tum population,  In this paper, we introduced a newway to update the quantum populationof QEA to avoid premature convergence
```

Sample:

```
'Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)\n\nMuhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba,
Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg\n\nAbstract\nWith advancement in Quantum computing, classical
algorithms are adapted and integrated\nwith Quantum properties such as qubit representation
and entanglement', ' Although these\nproperties perform better however pre-mature
convergence is the main issue in Quantum\nEvolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only
the best individual to update quan-\ntum population', ' In this paper, we introduced a new
way to update the quantum population\nof QEA to avoid premature convergence'
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this problem, each line has to be considered in conjunction with the line that follows it.  The rule here is to remove newlines if all of the following apply:

- it is not the last line of the file
- the line contains at least 2 words
- the next line contains at least 1 word

The problem is conveniently solved by using a generator function which will yield pairs of successive lines at a time.  This separates cleanly the logic for iterating over the file from the logic for deciding when to remove newlines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def num_words_line(line):
    return len(line.split())

def iter_lines(input_file):
    """
    yields pairs of adjacent lines
    """
    with open(input_file) as f:
        previous = next(f)
        for line in f:
            yield (previous, line)
            previous = line
        yield (line, None)


def fix_newlines(input_file, output_file):
    with open(output_file, "w") as fout:
        for line, next_line in iter_lines(input_file):
            if (next_line != None and
                num_words_line(line) > 1 and
                num_words_line(next_line) > 0):
                line = line.replace("\n", " ")
            fout.write(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fix_newlines("input.txt", "output.txt")
```

Gives:

```
Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)

Muhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg

Abstract
With advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integrated with Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement. Although these properties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in Quantum Evolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quan- tum population. In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum population of QEA to avoid premature convergence
```

Note, the number of words in each line is calculated twice. For slightly greater efficiency, this could be fixed, at the expense of slightly more code, by changing `iter_lines` to call `num_words_line` on each line as it is read in, and to yield the lengths of each line in the pair as well as the lines themselves.  But then there would be less clean separation of the logic between `iter_lines` and `fix_newlines`.

A slightly different version could be used for manipulating strings in memory in place of reading and writing files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def num_words_line(line):
    return len(line.split())


def iter_lines(input_string):
    """
    yields pairs of adjacent lines
    """
    iterator = iter(input_string.strip().split("\n"))
    previous = next(iterator)
    for line in iterator:
        yield (previous, line)
        previous = line
    yield (line, None)


def fix_newlines(input_string, from_file=True):
    output = ''
    for line, next_line in iter_lines(input_string):
        newline = not (next_line != None and
                       num_words_line(line) > 1 and
                       num_words_line(next_line) > 0)
        output += line
        if newline:
            output += "\n"
        else:
            output += " "
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_text = ['Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)\n\nMuhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg\n\nAbstract\nWith advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integrated\nwith Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement', ' Although these\nproperties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in Quantum\nEvolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quan-\ntum population', ' In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum population\nof QEA to avoid premature convergence',]
    str = ' '.join(input_text)

    print(fix_newlines(str))
```

Comment: your answer have multiple issues, it solves some too. But rahter then using 4 functions, I would like to use the answer given by vks because its compact.

Answer (score 0):

I will not even try to use a single regex here. The requirement is:

- if the newline if at end of file, keep it
- else if a newline is followed by another newline, keep it
- else if the line is *short*, keep the newline (short is probably less than 60 or 70)
- else if the newline is preceded by a dash (`-`) remove both the dash and the newline
- else replace the newline with a space

This should be rather robust, but I cannot imagine to fulfill that with regexes. Assuming input is:

```
orig = ['Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)\n\nMuhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg\n\nAbstract\nWith advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integrated\nwith Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement',
        ' Although these\nproperties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in Quantum\nEvolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quan-\ntum population',
        ' In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum population\nof QEA to avoid premature convergence']
```

I would use:

```
pre = '.'.join(orig).split('\n')
res = []
old = None
for line in pre:
    if old is None:
        old = line
        continue
    if len(line) == 0:
        res.extend([old, '\n'])
    elif len(old) < 70:
        res.extend([old, '\n'])
    elif old[-1] == '-':
        res.append(old[:-1])
    else:
        res.extend([old, ' '])
    old = line


text = ''.join(res)
```

It gives for `print(text)`

```
Balanced Quantum Classical Evolutionary Algorithm(BQCEA)

Muhammad Shahid, Hasan Mujtaba, Muhammad Asim, Omer Beg

Abstract
With advancement in Quantum computing, classical algorithms are adapted and integrated with Quantum properties such as qubit representation and entanglement. Although these properties perform better however pre-mature convergence is the main issue in Quantum Evolutionary Algorithms(QEA) because QEA uses only the best individual to update quantum population. In this paper, we introduced a new way to update the quantum population
```

Comment: this is output of your code.

B.a.l.a.n.c.e.d. .Q.u.a.n.t.u.m. .C.l.a.s.s.i.c.a.l. .E.v.o.l.u.t.i.o.n.a.r.y. .A.l.g.o.r.i.t.h.m.(.B.Q.C.E.A.). .

Comment: @shahidhamdam My input was a list not a string. If you start from a plain string, replace the initial `pre = '.'.join(orig).split('\n')` with a simple `pre = orig.split('\n')`